# Overwriting values of a union provides undefined behavior?

Tags: c, data-structures, unions

I am trying to understand what is happening with the value being stored in my union memory. I have this code snippet to use as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    
    union myUnion {
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
    };

    union myUnion u;

    u.i = 42;    // store an integer value in the union
    printf("%d\n", u.i);    // prints 42

    u.f = 3.14;  // store a float value in the union
    printf("%f\n", u.f);   // prints 3.140000

    u.c = 'A';   // store a character value in the union
    printf("%c\n", u.c);   // prints 'A'

    printf("%d\n", u.i);   // prints 1078523201
    printf("%f\n", u.f);  // print 3.139969
}
```

Everything works fine until this line `printf("%d\n", u.i);   // prints 1078523201` which is expected because the original int value of 42 should be overwritten in memory. Is this happening because it is printing the int (32 bits long) version of what remains in memory from previously setting the union?

```
Mem Add | Value

0x1000    ascii value of A from setting u.c (8 bits)
0x1001    remnants from setting u.f 
0x1002    remnants from setting u.f 
0x1003    remnants from setting u.f
```

But then if this is true, why does the print of u.f provide an accurate result? Is this because the floating point number was saved in a register and the code is just reusing that as opposed to going out to the memory location of the union?

Comment: I'm guessing it prints the float 'correctly' because accessing a member of a union, other than the one which was most recently set, is undefined behaviour, so the compiler is making some optimization like 'last time u.f was set it was 3.4, so I can just use that value in the printf call without actually reading it from the union'

Comment: If you write to a smaller type in the union, then read from a larger, the the value will be *indeterminate*. Also note that if the value you read happens to be a *trap value* then you will have undefined behavior. As for the `float` almost keeping its value, it all depends on the byte-order of `float`, how it's stored in memory, and what byte you happen to overwrite. You must always read from a member of the same size as the last one you wrote to.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Is it actually allowed in C? I was under the impression it was undefined behaviour in both languages

Comment: @Bwmat it is allowed, and is the standard correct way to do type punning in C.

Comment: Try printing the float with more significant digits, i.e. `%.9f`.

Comment: @Bwmat In C it's allowed to read from any member of the union, if it's of the same size as the one last written. It's called *type-punning*. It's not allowed in C.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Your comment wanted to say: "It's not allowed in C **++**"

Comment: `why does the print of u.f provide an accurate result?` I do not understand the question. `3.139969` is not "accurate"  `3.140000`. It's different..

Comment: @palacetrading, when  printing `u.f`, use `"%a"`.  It will be more informative.

Comment: Overwriting different members of a union produces... "interesting" behavior.  Add a field `short s;`, and say `u.s = 1234;`, and you'll probably see the `float` value perturbed more (my guess: 3.12514).

Comment: @palacetrading See updated answer. My first answer didn't explain it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this happening because it is printing the int (32 bits long) version of what remains in memory from previously setting the union?

Yes. And it's legal to do in C <sub>(see endnote)</sub>

For a union the individual members share the same memory.

So in your case `u.i` and `u.f` share the same memory (they are both 32 bits in your case). This means that when you set `u.i` to some value and then change `u.f` and afterwards reads `u.i` you'll see another result than the value you assigned to `u.i`.

`u.c` also share memory with `u.i` and `u.f` so when you assign a value to `u.c`, it will also change `u.i` and `u.f`.

In the end it's about how the bit pattern of an integer is stored and how the bit pattern of a float is stored and how the bit pattern of a char is stored. This include both the bit level encoding and endianess of your system.

Inside the computer there are bits. Sequences of bits. What they  mean depends on what you want them to mean... This is what the type system is doing for you. And unions is a way to look at the same memory (same bit pattern) as different types.

Here is your program with a little change. The code now dumps the raw memory of the union object.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union myUnion {
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
    unsigned uns;
};

void dump_union(union myUnion* u)
{
    unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)u;
    printf("union memory : ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(union myUnion); ++i) printf("%02X ", p[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main(void) 
{    
    union myUnion u;

    u.i = 42;    // store an integer value in the union
    printf("%d\n", u.i);    // prints 42
    dump_union(&u);

    u.f = 3.14;  // store a float value in the union
    printf("%f\n", u.f);   // prints 3.140000
    dump_union(&u);

    u.c = 'A';   // store a character value in the union
    printf("%c\n", u.c);   // prints 'A'
    dump_union(&u);

    printf("%d\n", u.i);   // prints 1078523201
    dump_union(&u);
    printf("%f\n", u.f);  // print 3.139969
    dump_union(&u);
    
    return 0;
}
```

On my system the output is:

```
42
union memory : 2A 00 00 00 

3.140000
union memory : C3 F5 48 40 

A
union memory : 41 F5 48 40 

1078523201
union memory : 41 F5 48 40 

3.139969
union memory : 41 F5 48 40
```

The first thing to notice is that my system is little endian. That means that the least significant byte of an object is stored at the lowest address.

So when you see `2A 00 00 00` in the above output, it means that `u.i` has the representation `0000002A` for the integer value 42 decimal.

Likewise when you see `C3 F5 48 40` it means that `u.f` has the representation `4048F5C3` for the float value 3.14

Assigning to `u.i` and `u.f` overwrites all of the unions memory because they are both 4 bytes on my system.

Assigning to `u.c` will however only change the byte at the lowest address and leave the reaming bytes unchanged, i.e. `C3 F5 48 40` becomes `41 F5 48 40`.

Due to my system being little endian it means that the bit pattern for `u.f` changes from `4048F5C3` to `4048F541`. Only the least significant byte was changed. Due to the way float is encoded this represents a minor change of the floating point value, i.e. when printing `u.f` the value changed from 3.14 to 3.139969

If you print `u.i` just before and after setting `u.c` you will see a similar change of the integer value.

*Endnote*

Changing the value of one union member and then reading it using another union member is something you shall do with great care. System endianess may impact the final result.

Another thing to take care about is trap representations. A valid bit pattern for one type may be a trap representation for another type. So you may end up with unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks, printing out the memory values really helped me to see what was going on! It makes sense that the difference of C3 and 41 in the LSBs bits of the floating-point number cause a slight change in the value of the float (3.14 vs. 3.139)

Answer (score 1):

*which is expected because the original int value of 42 should be overwritten in memory.*

When you assign 'A' (1 byte), you are not filling the remaining 3 bytes with 0s if that's what you mean.

You can reproduce the behaviour with `memcpy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    float f = 3.14;
    char c = 'A';
    int x = 42;

    memcpy(&x, &f, 4); // 1000000010010001111010111000011 
    memcpy(&x, &c, 1); // 1000000010010001111010101000001
                       //                  'A' = 01000001
    printf("%d\n", x);
    memcpy(&f, &x, 4);
    printf("%f\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1078523201
3.139969
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you get a different result, not by much but by little.

So the memory that changed when you wrote "A" also altered the float value, as expected.

Reading a member of a union which was not the last written to is not undefined behaviour and is OK in C.